# Как убрать из url схему и домен?

Tags: python, строки, url

Есть ссылка вида: `https://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242`

Как правильно ее обрезать, чтобы отбросить `https://domain.com`?

Comment: domain.com или http s://domain.com ?

Comment: @strawdog с https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "https://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242"
s = s.split("/", 3)[3]
```

```
s = "https://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242"
s = '/'.join(s.split('/')[3:])
```

Comment: нде............

Comment: @strawdog А что не так?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor извиняюсь, не так немного вопрос поставил. Отредактировал, посмотрите.

Comment: все так. я вижу, вы научились оперативно править ответы. ну да бог с ним.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Готово. Поправил.

Answer (score 5):

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

url = 'https://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242'

url_parts = list(urlparse(url))
url_parts[0] = ''  # scheme
url_parts[1] = ''  # netloc
print(urlunparse(url_parts))
```

***stdout:***

```py
/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = "https://domain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242"
res = re.search(r"//[^\/]+(.*)", text).group(1)
print(res)
```

> '/index.php?route=product/category&path=93_242'